# need help redirecting with fetch

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, fetch

I'm a bit new to backend programing so I'm kind of stuck with this.

I'm trying to redirect from my login web page to a second page galled "gerente". I've been using fetch since I'm also using mongoDB to save a the log-in data, but I haven't seemed to have any luck redirecting after clicking the log-in button but the data IS getting saved.

What would the missing code be?

this is my form in index.html:

```
            <form name="form" >
                <div class="form-control">
                    <label for="username">Usuario</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Ingrese su usuario..." required />
                </div>
                <div class="form-control">
                    <label for="room">Equipo</label>
                    <select name="room" id="room">
                        <option value="rojo">Equipo rojo</option>
                        <option value="amarillo">Equipo Amarillo</option>
                        <option value="blanco">Equipo Blanco</option>
                        <option value="azul">Equipo Azul</option>
                        <option value="negro">Equipo Negro</option>

                    </select>
                </div>

                
                
                <button id="login-gerente"  type="button" class="btn" >Gerente</button>
                <button id="login-mecanico" type="button" class="btn" >Mecanico</button>
            </form>
        </main>
```

This is the code for index.js:

```
window.onload = () => {
   
   document.getElementById("login-gerente").onclick = () => {
        console.log("inicio");
//recoger los datos del formulario 

let user = {};

user.username = document.getElementById("username").value;

user.room = document.getElementById("room").value;

console.log(user);



//crear el Json de la petición


//peticion post: utilizar fetch
fetch("/jugadores", {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user)
  })
  .then(json)
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Request failed', error);
  });

//validación de usuario


//redirección
       window.location.replace("/Gerente.html")
       
   }

    
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the redirect inside the `then` functions:

```
window.onload = () => {
   
   document.getElementById("login-gerente").onclick = () => {
        console.log("inicio");
//recoger los datos del formulario 

let user = {};

user.username = document.getElementById("username").value;

user.room = document.getElementById("room").value;

console.log(user);



//crear el Json de la petición


//peticion post: utilizar fetch
fetch("/jugadores", {
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user)
  })
  .then(json)
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log('Request succeeded with JSON response', data);
//redirección
       window.location.replace("/Gerente.html")
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log('Request failed', error);
//redirección
       window.location.replace("/Gerente.html")
  });

//validación de usuario



       
   }

    
};
```

Comment: that seemed to work, thank you. Also I noticed I had a typo in the json decleration after stringify I was calling json instead of user

Comment: Please consider approving the answer if it helped :)